# remove last comma from dictionary/list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to python to generate a script that generates unload command in redshift. I not an expert Python programmer. I need to where I can generate all columns for the unload list. If the column is of specific name, I need to replace with a function. The challenge I am facing is it appending "," to last item in the dictionary. Is there a way I can avoid the last comma? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import psycopg2 from psycopg2.extras 
import RealDictCursor 

try: 
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' port='5439' user='scott' host='something.redshift.amazonaws.com' password='tiger'"); 
except: 
    print "Unable to connect to the database"

conn.cursor_factory = RealDictCursor 
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.set_isolation_level( psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT )

try: 
    cur.execute("SELECT column from pg_table_def where schema_name='myschema' and table_name ='tab1' " ); 
except: 
    print "Unable to execute select statement from the database!"

result = cur.fetchall()   
print "unload mychema.tab1 (select " 

for row in result: 
    for key,value in row.items(): 
        print "%s,"%(value)

print ") AWS Credentials here on..."

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the join function on the list of values in each row:

```
print ",".join(row.values())
```

Briefly, the join function is called on a string which we can think of as the "glue", and takes a list of "pieces" as its argument. The result is a string of "pieces" "held together" by the "glue". Example:

```
>>> glue = "+"
>>> pieces = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> glue.join(pieces) 
"a+b+c"
```

(since row.values() returns a list, you don't actually need the comprehension, so it's even simpler than I wrote it at first)

Comment: Why I am getting an error NameError: name 'join' is not defined.

for row in result:
   print join(",", [value for value in row.values()])

print ") TO s3://"

conn.close()

Answer (score 0):

Infact, this worked better.

```
columns = []
for row in result:
        if (row['column_name'] == 'mycol1') or (row['column_name'] == 'mycol2') :
           columns.append("func_sha1(" + row['column_name'] + "||" + salt +")")
        else:
           columns.append(row['column_name'])

print selstr + ",".join(columns)+" ) TO s3://"
```

Thanks for your help, Jon